# Does Zend framework urldecode the params via the $request object

Tags: php, zend-framework, urlencode, urldecode

latetly on a legacy project I have to use Zend framework 1.2 :-(.

I find Zend to have too many levels of indirection and magic functions and I am not 100% sure about wheather it urldecodes the request params. It's also not stated in the docs.

So example if you have a request object and you do:

`$ntrack = $request->getParam('ntrack');`

Will `$ntrack` contain the urldecoded of ntrack or not?

**So far by my tests** it seems so, but I couldn't trace or be **confident** about this...

I checked the following classes and found no evidence of urldecoding wierd...

Classes I checked:

`Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract`

`Zend_Controller_Request_Http` which implements the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZF doesn't need to do this since PHP does this automatically. You can assume `$request->getParam('ntrack')` will give you the URL decoded version.

Comment: oh yes, correct. Now that I look it gets them from the superglobals so yes you are correct.

Comment: Too many platforms, forgot that php does that on top of the framework. Thanks.